# How to create Vertical drop down menu animated menu

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have been trying to make exact drop down which this website as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/

**Expected like below:**

[image: vertical menu]

Not getting what I am actually missing and the code below is not flexible like the above website vertical drop-down menu

[image: My vertical menu]

The sub-menus of my website is not properly coming half get cut

This is my website to which I applied the code below:

https://codemyquestion.blogspot.com/

**Code:**

```html
 <style>
    
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
      
     nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 180px;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
      /* Sub Menu */
    }
    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        background: #ebebeb;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear;
        -moz-transition: 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear;
        transition: 0.2s linear;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover {
        background: #f8f8f8;
        color: #515151;
    }
    nav ul li a .fa {
        width: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 5px;
        float:right;
    }
    nav ul ul {
        background-color:#ebebeb;
    }
    nav ul li ul li a {
        background: #f8f8f8;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    nav ul li ul li a:hover {
        background: #ebebeb;
        border-left: 4px solid #3498db;
    }
    
    
    
    
    </style>
    
    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <nav class='animated bounceInDown'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#profile'>Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href='#message'>Messages</a></li>
            <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#settings'>Settings<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Profile</a></li>
                
                </ul>
            </li>
        
            <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#Somethin'>Something<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Profile</a></li>
                
                </ul>
            </li>
        
        
            <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#message'>Help<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>FAQ's</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Submit a Ticket</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#settings'>Network Status</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
      
    </nav>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
    
    
    $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
    $(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
        $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
        $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
    });
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this styling

```
.widget ul {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#sidebar-left-1 .widget-content nav {
    width: unset !important;
}

#sidebar-left-1 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Where i need to add in the above css or my xml template of blogger

Comment: can you help me to add the inside sub item menu box left and right padding

Comment: You can add this styling with your custom left and right padding. 
#sidebar-left-1 nav ul li ul li a {
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-right: 30px;
}

Comment: I tried the changes it work like charm but one more issue i found is that the sub menu does not get close automatically when my mouse arrow is at different location

Comment: How can i fix that ... when i click the Setting option it displays the sub items  but if hover my mouse to any other place the opened drop-down deos not get close automatically

Comment: No not use to work can you help me with that how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I will challenge you on 'half get cut'. Is is actually completely visible as per this picture:

[image]

What you will need to do is add padding in the `ul` tag which will result in some space on the right:
[image]

Resulting in this:

[image]